# Python give an error to a program CONSTRUCTION TAKES NO ARGUMENTS

Tags: python-requests

I am attempting to make a class called Restaurant. Using _init() method for restaurant should store two attributes. I am attempting to make a method called describe_restaurant() and print that prints out two pieces of info.

I checked Stack Overflow to see if this problem has ever happened before.
I checked with the book I am learning from to see if they have a solution.

```
class Restaurant():
    def _init_(self,name,cusine):
       self.name = name
       self.cusine = cusine
describe_restaurant = Restaurant(Golden Eye,steak)
print("The" + describe_restaurant.name.title() + "opens today")
print ("The Golden Eye opens at 5pm and serves" + describe_restaurant.cusine.title() + ".")
```

I expect that class would store the two pieces of info (name and cuisine) and print it later.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of errors there - the main one being that `_init_` requires a double underscore:

```
class Restaurant():
     def __init__(self,name,cusine):
           self.name = name
           self.cusine = cusine

describe_restaurant = Restaurant('Golden Eye','steak') #note the quotes around the variables
print("The " + describe_restaurant.name.title() + " opens today")
print ("The Golden Eye opens at 5pm and serves " + describe_restaurant.cusine.title() + ".") #note the extra spaces in the two print statements
```

Output:

> The Golden Eye opens today
>
> The Golden Eye opens at 5pm and serves Steak.